# Laravel 7.28 "the file does not exist error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i'm building a project with laravel 7.28. i list all of documents with foreach without a problem. then i listed and linked all of the documents like this

```
@foreach($customer->documents as $document)
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @if($document->extension == 'pdf')
            <a href="{{ route('downloadDocument', $document->id) }}">
                <img src="/assets/images/pdf_icon.png" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif
        @if($document->extension == 'doc' || $document->extension == 'docx')
            <a href="{{ route('downloadDocument', $document->id) }}">
                <img src="/assets/images/docx_icon.png" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif
        @if($document->extension == 'xlsx')
            <a href="{{ route('downloadDocument', $document->id) }}">
                <img src="/assets/images/xlsx_icon.png" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif
        @if($document->extension == 'jpg' || $document->extension == 'jpeg'|| $document->extension == 'png'|| $document->extension == 'svg')
            <a href="{{ route('downloadDocument', $document->id) }}">
                <img src="/assets/images/photo1.png" alt="">
            </a>
        @endif
    </div>
@endforeach
```

then i wrote route like this;

```
Route::get('downloadDocument/{id}', 'CustomerController@downloadDocument')->name('downloadDocument');
```

downloadDocument function is;

```
    public function downloadDocument($id)
    {
        $path = '/assets/uploads/customers/';

        $file = Upload::findOrFail($id);

        $pathToFile = $path . $file->media;

        return response()->download($pathToFile);
    }
```

i'm sure that i have that file on database and on server or local. although i get error;

[image: error message]

is there anyone to help me?

Comment: can you show your `dd` on `$pathToFile` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### URL Path vs System Path

I believe you're confusing **URL path** from **system path**.

Browser see files with **URL paths** like this (http://foobar.com/assets/uploads/customers/xxx.png). When you print things to the template, the files are referenced in HTML as **URL path**. A path like `/assets/uploads/customers/xxx.png` is simply
URL with [implicit domain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#absolute_urls_vs_relative_urls).

From the *server program perspective*, the file is stored in your harddisk with **system paths** like:

- `C:\My Websites\foobar\public\assets\uploads\customers\xxx.png` (Windows); or
- `/home/foobar/web/public/assets/uploads/customers/xxx.png` (Linux or Macos).

So, although these paths look different, they might be referencing the same file. Just from different perspective.

### How to correctly build `$pathToFile`?

The `$pathToFile` parameter of [download](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/responses#file-downloads) needs to be the **system path** to the file. I don't believe the png file is at `/assets/uploads/customers/xxx.png` in your system (Putting an `assets` folder in system root `/` or `C:\` is quite unusual).

If the `assets/` folder is in your Laravel's `public/` folder, you can rewrite your method with [public_path()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-public-path) like this:

```php
    public function downloadDocument($id)
    {
        // Note: remove leading slash
        $path = 'assets/uploads/customers/';

        $file = Upload::findOrFail($id);

        // Note: apply public_path() helper function
        $pathToFile = public_path($path . $file->media);

        return response()->download($pathToFile);
    }
```

Documentation about `public_path()` in Laravel 7.x:

> ### public_path()
>
> The `public_path` function returns the fully qualified path to the `public` directory. You may also use the `public_path` function to generate a fully qualified path to a given file within the public directory:
>
> ```php
> $path = public_path();
>
> $path = public_path('css/app.css');
> ```

Comment: all of my documents, images is under public, under assets. i know it's not the right way but i've done it first. i changed the variable's name but it didn't work. is there any way that doesn't need to move all files to storage

Comment: @jigsaw075: That means you are not storing everything at system root. So my comment and suggestion make sense, right?

Comment: I don't think my suggestion includes moving anything.

Comment: @jigsaw075: I wrote an even longer answer. Hope this would clear things up for you.

Comment: removing leading splash worked for my case. i didn't understand your suggestion at first but i got it now. thank you